# Oracle DB - Set Input Number to exact length

Tags: oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I am trying to set a constraint where user are only allowed to input 11 digits into the Number Data Type (Phone Number). I've tried

```
alter table "booyeah" add constraint
"booyeah_CC1" check ( LENGTH("PHONE_NO") = 11)
/
```

and

```
alter table "booyeah" add constraint
"booyeah_CC1" check ( PRECISION("PHONE_NO") = 11)
/
```

but got an error. For the first one, I kept getting error because it's not detecting the character length, while the second one, gave me an invalid identifier.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If there's no constrain check for Number, my alternative for this would be to change the data type to VARCHAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the data type for that column to `varchar(11)`.  If it must be exactly 11 characters every time, a check constraint will guarantee that: `check (length(phone_no) = 11)`. To guarantee length and "numerality" (all digits, no letters), use

```
check (length(phone_no) = 11 and 
       regexp_like(phone_no, '^[[:digit:]]{11}$')
)
```

If you have to use a numeric type--and this is a bad idea--your best bet is probably numeric(11,0).

A check constraint can help you restrict the range of valid input, but no numeric types store leading zeroes. You'll have to jump through unnecessary and avoidable hoops if something like `00125436754` is a valid phone number.

Comment: @MikeSherill I know changing the datatype to varchar(11) will work (as I've mentioned on the comment above), but is there any way to do the check (input validation) for Number datatype instead?

Comment: @Catcall I've tested on my other table earlier, setting a datatype of varchar(5). I input 3 characters, and oracle accepted my input (since it is less than 5 characters). Clearly I require a check constraint if I want a precise input.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I've tried inputting the phone number without the check, and it ignores the leading zeroes. Guess changing the datatype to varchar it is. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following check constraint:

```
... check (length(n||'')=11)
```

This check constraint is sufficiently simple. And you don't have to change the data type from `number` to `varchar2`, and don't have to check the input contains character other than digits.

I created simple table and checked whether it works properly:

```
create table t (n number check (length(n||'')=11));

insert into t values (1234567890); -- 10 digits
=> ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_552B1.SYS_C001297489) violated : insert into t values (1234567890)

insert into t values (12345678901);
=> Record Count: 0; Execution Time: 1ms

insert into t values (123456789012); -- 12 digits
=> ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_552B1.SYS_C001297489) violated : insert into t values (123456789012)
```

Another way is to use `log` of base 10: (looks more complicated)

```
... check (trunc(log(10,phone_no)) = 10)
```

If the given number has 11 digits, its `log` value would be 10.xxxx.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this way. But it seems long-winded compared to changing the datatype to varchar. Guess, checking the length of Number seems complicated compared to varchar... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use `varchar`. If you use `varchar`, then you should make sure that the input data don't contain letters or special characters for data integrity.

Comment: I recently found simpler way to do this and edited my answer.