# Restricting the exact number of numbers input in a field Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I am trying to make a field for telephone numbers that requires no more, no less than 10 numbers. I tried 
Telephone number(10) CHECK (Telephone=10) but it doesn't work, and neither does adding it as a constraint after the attributes.

Comment: `CHECK (LENGTH(Telephone) = 10)`

Comment: it says LEN is an invalid identifier

Comment: Sorry `LENGTH` for oracle.

Comment: it's giving me this: SQL Error: ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
02438. 00000 -  "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"
*Cause:    attempted to define a column check constraint that references
           another column.
*Action:   define it as a table check constriant.

Comment: If a phone number can have leading zeros, then it shouldn't be stored in a NUMBER column but rather a VARCHAR2 or CHAR column. I suggest looking at Oracle's regular expression support. You can use a regular expression in a column constraint.

Comment: This is a syntax erro, how are you adding the constraint ?

Comment: Have you seen this _Stack Overflow_ question: [Oracle DB - Set Input Number to exact length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577451/oracle-db-set-input-number-to-exact-length)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check constraint, like so:

```
create table t (id int primary key, telephone varchar2(10), check(length(telephone) = 10))
```

Or if telephone number is an integer:

```
create table t (
    id int primary key, 
    telephone int, 
    check(telephone>= 1000000000 and telephone < 10000000000)
);
```

Comment: What happens if the phone number's first digit is zero?

Comment: @Abra: then it's a string, so you want to use the first expression.

Answer (score 1):

Telephone numbers are generally stored as strings, not numbers.  First, the number is not really a number.  It doesn't make sense, for instance, to add two of them together.  Second, leading zeros can matter.

So, I would recommend:

```
telephone varchar2(10) check (length(telephone) = 10)
```

If you want to keep it as a number, you can use a range:

```
telephone number(10, 0) check (telephone >= 1000000000 and
                               telephone < 10000000000
                              )
```

This is explicit that there are no decimal places.

Comment: Oracle doesn't care whether parameter for a string operator is numeric or string. Using `check ( length(telephone) =10 )` is enough also for numeric type telephone column.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . I think it is a bad idea to implicitly convert number for this purpose (for one thing).  Second, if you are not careful, then 123.456789 would match -- as would -123456789.

Comment: yes, good catch for -123456789 but not valid for 123.456789. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41d217ec6ab006fdb63722433396ff9a) Btw +1